# Created Nested JSON array from JSON array

Tags: c#, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am pretty new to JSON and C# and have created an Azure Function that ties back to Snowflake which requires a very specific type of JSON response. I would like assistance if any in turning a JSON response I'm getting to a slightly different formatted response.

```
{
  "access_token": "access token value here" , "user": "user_val"
}
```

to looking like

```
{
    "data":
        [
            [ 0, { "access_token" : "access token value here",  "user" : "user_val" } ]
        ]
}
```

I need create a nested array with "data" as the parent and a row number response starting at 0.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
  ""access_token"": ""access token value here"" , ""user"": ""user_val""
}";
        Access a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Access>(json);
        
        var accessCollection = new AccessCollection
        {
            Data = new List<Access> { a }
        };
        
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accessCollection, Formatting.Indented);      
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class Access
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public string User
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class AccessCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Access> Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In addition, I consider the inner array is not usual because the data type are int and object. In general, they should be of same type. Because of that, I use a single dimensional array instead.
Please modify the codes according to situation.

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1gBgKr)

Comment: This helped me get much closer, any ideas on how to insert a counter before the inner array? Also needing extra [ ] to close this off. This is a very strange format that Snowflake uses for response JSON in external functions.

Comment: Could use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic). [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QRjJuh)